# why does the data couldn't show in the viewpage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is the html code:

```
<li ng-repeat="data in spreadGroupData" ng-click="channelList(data.campaigns,data.name)"><a href="javascript:void(0)">{{data.name}}</a></li>`
```

this is the code i write in the services.js:

```
services.getChannelName = function($scope,channelidList){
        httpurl = "api/account/"+nowuID+"/channel/channellist?id=" + channelidList;
        $http.get(httpurl).success(function(data){
            if(data.length>0){
                $scope.spreadGroupData = [];
                for(var i in data){
                    var group = {};
                    group.campaigns = data[i].id;
                    group.name = data[i].name;
                    $scope.spreadGroupData.push(group);
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

there are data in $scope.spreadGroupData,why couldn't show in the view page?

Now I know I shouldn't use `$scope` in the service,but the param 'channelidList' I get it from another service method. How to rewrite this all?

```
services.getListData = function(scope,flag){
         var reportList = "quality_report",merger = true;
         if(typeof flag!='undefined' && flag == 1){
             reportList = "fakequality_report";
             merger = false;
         }
        var cids = scope.spreadUrls,dateArr=scope.date.split(" - "),startDate = "",endDate = "",channelids = "";
        if(dateArr.length==1){
            startDate = endDate = dateArr[0];
        }else{
            startDate = dateArr[0];
            endDate = dateArr[1];
        }
        if(cids!=null){
            if(cids!='All'){
                channelids = "&channelid="+cids.join(",");
            }
            if(scope.selecteds != -1 &&  typeof(scope.selecteds) != "undefined"){
                httpurl = "api/app/"+scope.selecteds+"/report/"+reportList+"?startdate="+startDate+"&enddate="+endDate+channelids;
                $http.get(httpurl).success(function(data,status){
                    scope.tabTitle = data.name;
                     var tableList = services.colToRow(data.val),cidlen = cids.length;
                     scope.tabTotal = services.dataToTotal(data.val,cidlen);
                     var key = data.key,tabname = [],zero = [],tabListInfo = [],allnames = scope.spreadNames;
                     for(var i=0;i<scope.tabTotal.length;i++){
                        zero[i] = 0;
                     }
                     for(i=0;i<cidlen;i++){
                        var idx = $.inArray(allnames[i],key);
                        tabListInfo[i] = new Array();
                        if(idx>-1){
                            tabListInfo[i] = tableList[idx];
                        }else{
                            tabListInfo[i] = zero;
                        }

                        if(merger){
                            var temp = [];
                            for(var j=0;j<tabListInfo[i].length;j++){
                                temp[j] = tabListInfo[i][j];
                            }
                            temp.unshift(scope.spreadNames[i]);
                            tabListInfo[i] = temp;
                        }
                     }
                     var channelIdList = [];
                     if(key.length>0){
                         var n = 0;
                         for(var i in scope.spreadData){
                             for(var j in key){
                                 if(key[j] == scope.spreadData[i].name){
                                     n++;
                                     channelIdList.push(scope.spreadData[i].channel);
                                     if(n>20) break;
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                     services.getChannelName(scope,channelIdList.join(","));
                     scope.tabname = scope.spreadNames;
                     if(merger){
                         var tabListObj = [];
                         if(reportList == "quality_report"){
                             for(var i = 0; i <tabListInfo.length; i++){
                                 tabListObj.push({
                                     "name" : tabListInfo[i][0],
                                     "hitNum" : tabListInfo[i][1],
                                     "reSchedulNum" : tabListInfo[i][2],
                                     "activeDevice" : tabListInfo[i][3],
                                     "activeRate" : tabListInfo[i][4],
                                     "payment" : tabListInfo[i][5],
                                     "spdID" : cids[i]
                                 });
                             }
                         }
                         scope.tabListInfo = tabListObj;
                     }else{
                         if(reportList == "fakequality_report"){
                             var tabListObj = [];
                             for(var i = 0; i <tabListInfo.length; i++){
                                 tabListObj.push({
                                     "name" : scope.tabname[i],
                                     "reSchedulNum" : tabListInfo[i][0],
                                     "hitNum" : tabListInfo[i][1],
                                     "errHitNum" : tabListInfo[i][2],
                                     "errHitRate" : tabListInfo[i][3],
                                     "activeDevice" : tabListInfo[i][4],
                                     "errActDevice" : tabListInfo[i][5],
                                     "errActRate" : tabListInfo[i][6],
                                     "spdID" : cids[i]
                                 });
                             }
                             scope.tabListInfo = tabListObj;
                         }else{
                             scope.tabListInfo = tabListInfo;
                         }
                     }
                     scope.spreadIDs = cids;
                }).error(function(data){
                    services.loginTimeout(data);
                });
                }
            }
    };
```

Comment: You are overwrite group in each iteration. You must put var group = {} out of loop.

Comment: I need to push a new object to the array, so i need to overwrite group. There are there objects in $scope.spreadGroupData,I have consoled it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never pass `$scope` object to service, service should always have a reusable method which will exposed. I'd suggest you service method should return promise to the controller caller method, and caller method will implement the binding logic inside controller promise success method.

**Service Method**

```
services.getChannelName = function(channelidList) {
    httpurl = "api/account/" + nowuID + "/channel/channellist?id=" + channelidList;
    return $http.get(httpurl).success(function(data) {
        return data;
    }).error(function(err) {
        return err;
    });
};
```

**Controller Method**

```
$scope.getChannelName = function() {
    $scope.spreadGroupData = [];
    service.getChannelName(channelidList).then(function(data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            for (var i in data) {
                var group = {};
                group.campaigns = data[i].id;
                group.name = data[i].name;
                $scope.spreadGroupData.push(group);
            }
        }
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("Error" + err);
    })
}
```

**Update**

Whole idea about the code like below. Need to maintain proper code stack resolve.
First service method will return promise, on resolved of it you need to do change in some scope variables, then you will call second service method which has promise, on resolved of it you need to update scope.

**Code**

```
services.getListData(flag).then(function(data) { //you may need to pass multiple parameter to this
    //then do scope operation
    service.getChannelName(channelidList).then(function(res) {
        if (res.length > 0) {
            for (var i in data) {
                var group = {};
                group.campaigns = data[i].id;
                group.name = data[i].name;
                $scope.spreadGroupData.push(group);
            }
        }
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("Error" + err);
    });
})
```

Comment: @ParkerSong This would the best way to do cod in angular way , Do upvote if you can.. Thanks :)

Comment: I just joined a new company and beginning to learn ng. The code was wrriten by the other colleague, in the service.js she almost use the scope in every method. As you suggested, I need to rewrite the whole service.:-(

Comment: @ParkerSong  Yes $scope should be depend on service and service should never update `$scope` directly, it considered as code smell in angular..I'd personally prefer to rewrite a code..As per angular code should separate as it use mvc pattern

Comment: The param is from another service method. What should I do to rewrite this service?

Comment: @ParkerSong that is what you are trying to say..it'll mess you are making you service tightly coupled with particular controller..

Comment: **Pull one hair and the whole body is affected** this is a really hard work

Comment: @ParkerSong Its my pleasure, sorry to force you to do rework, but I'm sure, after this re factoring you will be having good understanding about angular

Comment: For more understanding of service do refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory/28262966#28262966

Answer (score 1):

I only saw one little thing that might be cause a problem, there is a missing **var** keyword in front of the **httpurl** variable and I only add that to below demo.

The view you need to show your data:

```
<body ng-controller="myController">
    Spread Group Data
    <br />
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    <li ng-repeat="data in spreadGroupData"
        ng-click="channelList(data.campaigns,data.name)">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">{{data.name}}</a>
    </li>
</body>
```

I used a mock json provide to simulate your service and call it in a controller directly:

```
// Prepared a mock json array on the http://beta.json-generator.com and below url returns:
// [{"name":"Item 1","id":1},{"name":"Item 2","id":2},{"name":"Item 3","id":3},{"name":"Item 4","id":4}]
var httpurl = "http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/LoUmNC4";

$http.get(httpurl).success(function(data) {
  if (data.length > 0) {
    $scope.spreadGroupData = [];
    for (var i in data) {
      var group = {};
      group.campaigns = data[i].id;
      group.name = data[i].name;
      $scope.spreadGroupData.push(group);
    }
  }
});
```

If your service is independent from your controller, then you can pass $scope to your service method. But in this demo I implemented the http call block directly in a main controller. Besides this as @pankajparkar's said do not use the $scope in factories or service unrelated services and take and use response data from that like services. Please check *promise*  and *$q* in order to handle asynchronous calls.

This is a working demo: [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JPuHhCisMGDhzd6D1mLf?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, I have another promblem,please see the question I just updated.

Comment: There is question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509457/passing-current-scope-to-an-angularjs-service. Passing $scope to a service is not a best-practice but you can use if you have to do and you do not have any choice. If you ask me "if it works leave it alone".

Answer (score 0):

Place  $scope.spreadGroupData = []; outside $http call :-

```
services.getChannelName = function($scope,channelidList){
        httpurl = "api/account/"+nowuID+"/channel/channellist?id=" + channelidList;
        $scope.spreadGroupData = [];
        $http.get(httpurl).success(function(data){
            if(data.length>0){
                for(var i in data){
                    var group = {};
                    group.campaigns = data[i].id;
                    group.name = data[i].name;
                    $scope.spreadGroupData.push(group);
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: why you are encouraging people to use scope inside service method

Comment: @pankajparkar you are right i was just giving the OP answer and forgot :-P to elaborate about best practice not to use $scope inside the service .  :-) Thanks :)