# Can you reuse $scope.$watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

I found some code I want to copy / paste and use in two controllers. It watches something.

```
$scope.$watch('thing', function (thing) {
  // do cool stuff with thing
}
```

Instead of copy/paste, I'd like to put it in a service and use the service from both controllers sortof like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('CoolService',
  function () {
    $scope.$watch('thing', function (thing) {
      // do cool stuff with thing
    }
}
```

Now if I do this, it won't know what `$scope` is, right? (*According to some reading, it won't let me do that anyway.*)

Nevertheless, I'd like to say, *If you have this service, you get this watch*.

There's a hint I can do this: [Passing current scope to an AngularJS Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509457/passing-current-scope-to-an-angularjs-service/25451709#25451709)

So I took his example, fixed it, and scope.watch works in there, but now I can't set other scope variables inside the watch. I just don't know enough javascript to do it, but I'm close. I really think it will work with the right syntax...

```js
angular.module('blah', []);

angular.module('blah').factory('BlahService', function() {
  //constructor
  function BlahService(scope) {
      this._scope = scope;
      this.myFunc = function(){
        this._scope.otherVar = this._scope.someVar;
      };
      this._scope.$watch('someVar', function(someVar) {
        // do cool stuff with thing
        _scope.otherVar = this._scope.someVar; // undefined
        this._scope.otherVar = this._scope.someVar; // undefined
        this.myFunc(); // undefined
        BlahService.prototype._someFunction(); // works, but...
        return someVar;
      });

    }

    //wherever you'd reference the scope
  BlahService.prototype._someFunction = function() {
    if (this._scope['someVar'] == 1) // undefined
      this._scope['someVar']++;
  }

  return BlahService;

});

angular.module('blah').controller('BlahCtrl', function($scope, BlahService) {
  $scope.someVar = 4;
  $scope.BlahService = new BlahService($scope);
});

angular.module('blah').controller('Blah2Ctrl', function($scope, BlahService) {
  $scope.someVar = 6;
  $scope.BlahService = new BlahService($scope);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="blah">
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="BlahCtrl">
      1a. <input ng-model="someVar">
      1b. <input ng-model="otherVar">
    </div>
<div ng-controller="Blah2Ctrl">
      2. <input ng-model="someVar">
  2b. <input ng-model="otherVar">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The key feature that this snippet has is that the scopes are different scopes. It doesn't act like a singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it, and it allows me to set other members of the scope from within the watch:

```js
angular.module('blah', []);

angular.module('blah').factory('BlahService', function() {
  //constructor
  function BlahService(scope) {
    this._scope = scope;
    this.myFunc = function() {
      this._scope.otherVar = this._scope.someVar;
    };
    this._scope.$watch('someVar', function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
      // do cool stuff with thing
      scope.otherVar = Number(scope.someVar) + 1;
      return newValue;
    });
  }
  return BlahService;
});

angular.module('blah').controller('BlahCtrl', function($scope, BlahService) {
  $scope.someVar = 4;
  $scope.BlahService = new BlahService($scope);
});

angular.module('blah').controller('Blah2Ctrl', function($scope, BlahService) {
  $scope.someVar = 6;
  $scope.BlahService = new BlahService($scope);
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="blah">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="BlahCtrl">
      1a. <input ng-model="someVar">
      1b. <input ng-model="otherVar">
    </div>
<div ng-controller="Blah2Ctrl">
      2. <input ng-model="someVar">
  2b. <input ng-model="otherVar">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing $scopes to a service sounds like a recipe for memory leaks.  If nothing else it's the long way around.

Instead consider just doing this in each directive:

```
scope.$watch('thing', function (thing) {
    coolService.doCoolStuffWith(thing);
}
```

Let the directive do the watching of its own scope, and put the shared functionality in the service.

Comment: I answered my own question but if my answer causes me grief I'll try yours. Thank you for answering. Maybe I'm taking DRY too far...we'll see.